# Need Help pulling longest and shortest time in a timespan

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan

I have a list that prints a timespan variable that I am currently displaying in my application for each logged in agent. When the list prints on my datagrid is has a column for each agent and a timespan listed for each agent. I'm trying to pull which agent currently has the longest timespan and display that in another variable to I can show the longest available time without an agent being on the phone. I'm currently using a foreach loop for my list and tried to extract the time out of my timespan variable and frankly I guess I'm not understanding how this list works (amateur programmer here). listed below I'm showing what I use for the timespan math only and then the entire foreach loop below it.

```
var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;

newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>(AgentDateTimeStateChange);

var min = listofTimeSpans.Min();
var max = listofTimeSpans.Max();
```

I know a lot of this isn't needed but I posted it to try to develop an idea of what i'm attempting to accomplishe

```
foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();
    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;
    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;
    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;
    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>(AgentDateTimeStateChange);
    var min = listofTimeSpans.Min();
    var max = listofTimeSpans.Max();
    int breakCount = 0;
    foreach (var agent in newAgentList)
    {                             
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.AuxReasons) && agent.AuxReasons.StartsWith("Break"))
           breakCount++;
       }

       int lunchCount = 0;
       foreach (var agent in newAgentList)
       {                            
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(agent.AuxReasons) && agent.AuxReasons.StartsWith("Lunch"))
               lunchCount++;
           }
           newAgentList.Add(newAgents);
           if (breakCount > 2)
           {
               Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Action)(() =>
               {
                   inBreakData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                   inBreakData.Text = breakCount.ToString();
               }));
           }else if (breakCount > 3)
           {
               Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
               {
                  inBreakData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                  inBreakData.Text = breakCount.ToString();
                }));
           }
           else
           {
               Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
               {
                   inBreakData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                   inBreakData.Text = breakCount.ToString();
               }));
           }

           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { inLunchData.Text = lunchCount.ToString(); }));
       }
```

Comment: so what the question is? p.s. your `else if (breakCount > 3)` is unreachable because of `if (breakCount > 2)` - every value that is bigger than 3 is always bigger than 2, for example 4 is bigger than 2 so it won't even go to > 3 statement

Comment: Thank you. I thought I corrected that already but guess I didn't. Either way. I'm trying to take the largest time that shows for all agents in agentDateTimeStateChange and print that time to a new TimeSpan Variable so I can display only the largest time. When I do new list<TimeSpan>(AgentDateTimeStateChange) it says that it does not exist in current context even though its directly above it and I use it in other area's of the code.  I'm assuming I'm creating this list of times wrong. and I'm also assuming this is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get from comments, you are having problem with `var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>(AgentDateTimeStateChange);`

You don't have variable called `AgentDateTimeStateChange`, you have a property of `NewAgent` class with that name. So you have 2 options here

```
var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
listofTimeSpans.Add(newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange);
```

or

```
var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
listofTimeSpans.Add(timeSpanSince);
```

either of them should work. Let me know if this answers your question.

**UPDATE**

This will fix your exception, but not going to resolve your issue, because you're going to override your list, min, and max values on each iteration. 
The simplest way would be to pull the list out of the loop and do min/max outside of it.

```
var listofTimeSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();
foreach(...) {
    ...
    listofTimeSpans.Add(timeSpanSince);
    ...
}
var min = listofTimeSpans.Min();
var max = listofTimeSpans.Max();
```

Comment: when doing newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange which is something I also tried it is trying to convert system.timespan to int and complaining.

Comment: yeah my mistake, you can't pass your item as a parameter to the List constructor. You have to initialize it and then use listofTimeSpans.Add() like in my update

Comment: This ended up displaying the data I need, I just have to construct the appropriate if statements to display the data I want when I want now. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: so I had originally marked this as resolved but turns out it is not. when I print var max to a text box it is displaying a time in hours...even if an agent just hit an available state which should be seconds. I think max is adding all the times together and giving me a max or something. its the only thing that make sense.

Comment: i guess this could be my error also. when i add a break point in it gives me a list of all 33 agents and their timespans in current state but the time spans are huge. way more then they should be. something is wrong with the data.

Comment: I know what's happening!! so...i need to display max time of only agents that have a state of avail-in. so i need to add agent state to the list and separate agents avail and only pull the max time for agents that have a state of avail-in. should i post a new question or are you able to assist with this.

Comment: I figured out what happened and its going to cause a bigger problem then I thought. if I can't figure it out I'll post a new question. re-marked your answer as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: well, I don't know a lot about your software, but if you need only the avail-in agents you can just add if statement around your list.Add() method: `if (newAgent.Avail) listofTimeSpans.Add(timeSpanSince);`

Comment: Thank you. I really have to stop over thinking things. I was going to do that initially but I thought if any of the agents = avail it would just add them all. my mindset when it comes to programming needs some work I think. haha. again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over thinking it a skosh. You have an object NewAgent.

Define a property in that object as something like TimeInState and make it read only:

```
public TimeSpan TimeInState {get { return DateTime.Now - AgentDateTimeChange; } }
```

This will always get you the current time in state when you read based on the NewAgent Object. You fill out the AgentDateTimeChange (I'm assuming this is the last update time for whatever state they are in) and then TimeInState comes back for you. If you have a List of NewAgents then you can always order by TimeInState to get the descending or ascending list:

```
(List<NewAgent>).OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeInstate);
```

Comment: I think this will give me a list of all times but I only want to print the single largest time in the list. I'm assuming I can continue to do that with the code I've already provided in my question?

Comment: also. AgentDateTimeChange is of type timespan and when defining the property like you did above it complains because it can not convert system.datetime to system.timespan

Comment: The order by descending will get you the largest time to get the largest you get: 

(List<NewAgent>).OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeInstate)[0].TimeInState;

Comment: ok so this will give me exactly what I am looking for, I just have to figure out the datetime to timespan thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to pull which agent currently has the longest timespan

if you rephase that then you want the first agent when ordered by timespan  largest to smallest

ie

```
var agent = agents.OrderByDescending(a=>a.TimeSpan).FirstOrDefault();
```

where TimeSpan is your calculation for how long this timeSpan has been